# Printing values of attribute in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

This question may sound similar ,but non of the previous questions have been helpful to me.

In my app there are 2 activities,and 5 .java classes.
I need to know the value of an attribute which is there in the dependent classes (parking.java) (not in Main_Activity).

Till time i have tried putting

System.out.println ,Log.d/e/v/i ,but nothing seems to print my value.

what ever operations I tried,I did  only in that particular class.(parking.java)
Also I have set debuggable =true in manifest file.

why the values are not getting printed ,am I putting them in wrong place ? ,or something else needs to be done

Please help

Here is the code

```
 public void setLongitude(String Longitude){

        try
        {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(sd.toString()); 
            _longitude=getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
            Log.e("Tagname","_longitude");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i have put Tagname as "Nihar"
still no success,
This is the change I have made ,

```
try
        {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(sd.toString()); 
            _longitude=getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
            Log.v("Tagname",_longitude);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is the image 
[image]

Comment: are you getting system log messages in logcat or logcat doesn't work at all?

Comment: am getting system log msgs

Comment: Can you show us the portion of code where you ask to print that value?

Comment: Guys ,am completely new to android ,to be fare this is my first app 
if some thing silly ,then sorry ,here is the piece of code in side a setter method of class parkinginfo.java .

i want to print the value of _longiutde.

Comment: No problem Nihar, people are her to help. First of all change the Log line to : Log.v("ParkingInfo", _longitude); . Second, for what I see you are not using the input parameter of setLongitude, why? Anyway let's start with removing the inverted commas from _longitude .. and be sure that in DDMS you setted the logcat to show output of "verbose" level.

Comment: i was so desperate to print anything on the screen ...may be thats why 
however can u help me regarding how to set the DDMS to show the output of verbose level
and one more question why the hell Sys.out.print not working ???
used to be my favorite cmnd in java

Comment: You have to use System.out.println("Something"). Regarding DDMS (I suppose that you are able to open it..), open the LogCat perspective and on the top-right portion of the screen there is a drop-down menu with verbose, assert, debug etc.. You just select verbose.

Comment: any more suggestions ???